# Guaranteeing order of file content when fetched through multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose there are 100 files numbered from 1-100 and you need to read these files in parallel using multi-threading. Is there any way to print the content of these file in order i.e 1-100 ?

Comment: Why read the contents concurrently if you are going to print the output serially? It seems like you should simply read each file one at a time, in numeric order from 1 to 100, and print the output that way. Introducing concurency here does not (from your question text) appear to be necessary.

Comment: one of my friend was asked this question in his interview hence curious to know if it can be achieved or not .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, provided you can hold the contents of all of them in memory.

The basic idea is to keep on storing the `Future` to when you would complete reading/processing the files in order and then `get` the values from the future in the order they were created.

```
        List<String> filePathsInOrder = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Future<String>> fileOutputsInOrder = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String filePath : filePathsInOrder) {
            fileOutputsInOrder.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    return Files.readString(Paths.get(filePath));
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }));
        }
        for (Future<String> fileOutput : fileOutputsInOrder){
            System.out.println(fileOutput.get());
        }
```

You would of course need to take of subtleties like exception handling, in case of your reads fail, etc. This done above, as that is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. You can create a `String` array of 100 elements and fill the element of proper index, so, if you read file 55, then you set the 54th `String` (remember, indexing starts from 0) to it. If you wait for all threads to be finished, then you can just loop this array and print its contents. You can also decide not to wait. In that case you can have a numeric n value (initialized to -1) which would denote which was the last file successfully printed and upon each thread end you could print out the files you can at that point.